# Can a 433mhz receiver receive data from a 433mhz tag/fob?

Tags: arduino-nano, rfid

If I use a 433mhz receiver on an Arduino Nano, will it detect a 433mhz tag? I'm not talking about the transmitter that is shown below but a tag/key fob.

[image: Receiver]

Example of 433mhz tag
[image]

Comment: Nothing in the receiver can power the fob.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the fob has its own power from a battery.

Comment: It might be possible to hack the patented protocol :) http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/186315/file-2401365665-pdf/docs/Assets/m163-i_tech_spec_sheet.pdf

Comment: That should be possible. You'd have to reverse engineer the encoding and protocol though.